# Detecting Excel column data types in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

New to Python and Pandas here. I am trying to read an Excel file off of S3 (using boto3) and read the headers (first row of the spreadsheet) and determine what data type each header is, *if this is possible to do*. If it is, I need a map of key-value pairs where each key is the header name and value is its data type. So for example if the file I fetch from S3 has the following data in it:

```
Date,Name,Balance
02/01/2022,Jerry Jingleheimer,45.07
02/14/2022,Jane Jingleheimer,102.29
```

Then I would be looking for a map of KV pairs like so:

- Key 1: "Date", Value 1: "datetime" (or whatever is the appropriate date type)
- Key 2: "Name", Value 2: "string" (or whatever is the appropriate date type)
- Key 3: "Balance", Value 3: "numeric" (or whatever is the appropriate date type)

So far I have:

```
s3Client = Res.resource('s3')
obj = s3Client.get_object(Bucket="some-bucket", Key="some-key")
file_headers = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(obj['Body'].read()), engine="openpyxl").columns.tolist()
```

I'm just not sure about how to go about extracting the data types that Pandas has detected or how to generate the map.

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use `dtypes`:

```
>>> df.dtypes.to_dict()
{'Date': dtype('<M8[ns]'), 'Name': dtype('O'), 'Balance': dtype('float64')}

>>> {k: v.name for k, v in df.dtypes.to_dict().items()}
{'Date': 'datetime64[ns]', 'Name': 'object', 'Balance': 'float64'}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to check this [pandas tutorial](https://www.w3resource.com/python-exercises/pandas/excel/python-pandas-excel-exercise-2.php).

The `pandas.read_excel('my_file.xlsx').dtypes` should give you the types of the columns.